# PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pyautogui, pyscreeze

my code:

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
x, y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("slorixsh.png", confidence=0.5)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    x, y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("slorixsh.png", confidence=0.5)
  File "C:\Users\mrnug\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 231, in _couldNotImportPyScreeze
    raise PyAutoGUIException(
pyautogui.PyAutoGUIException: PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze. (This is likely because you're running a version of Python that Pillow (which pyscreeze depends on) doesn't support currently.) Please install this module to enable the function you tried to call.
```

line 231 in that error:

```
 raise PyAutoGUIException(
            "PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze. (This is likely because you're running a version of Python that Pillow (which pyscreeze depends on) doesn't support currently.) Please install this module to enable the function you tried to call."
        )
```

somehow it doesnt work
i just reinstalled and updated that modules:

```
pyscreeze, opencv, pyautogui, pillow
```

Comment: It seems there is some kid of bug with pyautogui.
 
It works for me on Linux where is have:
Pillow                   10.1.0
PyAutoGUI                0.9.54
PyScreeze                0.1.30

But it doesn't work on windows with these versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you can fix it by this

`pip install pyscreeze`

```
import pyscreeze
import time

time.sleep(5)
x, y = pyscreeze.locateOnScreen("slorixsh.png", confidence=0.5)
```