# PyAutoGUI error (python, visual studio, MacOS)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

I have a simple python script in visual studio on MacOS. Everytime I try to run it I get the following error please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrGru.jpg)

Kyles-MacBook-Pro-12:Python brogan$  cd /Users/brogan/Desktop/Python ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/brogan/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 56397 -- /Users/brogan/Desktop/Python/AutoGUI.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/brogan/Desktop/Python/AutoGUI.py", line 3, in 
res = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Apple_Logo.png")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyautogui/**init**.py", line 228, in _couldNotImportPyScreeze
raise PyAutoGUIException(
pyautogui.PyAutoGUIException: PyAutoGUI was unable to import pyscreeze. (This is likely because you're running a version of Python that Pillow (which pyscreeze depends on) doesn't support currently.) Please install this module to enable the function you tried to call.

Ive tried installing PyScreeze

Kyles-MacBook-Pro-12:Python brogan$ pip3 install PyScreeze
Requirement already satisfied: PyScreeze in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (0.1.30)

This is the response... I believe I already have it.

Comment: This question was answered before, you can find answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925578/pyautogui-was-unable-to-import-pyscreeze

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to install pillow.

pip3 install pillow

Answer (score 0):

try installing pyscreeze

```
pip install pyscreeze
```

and then use the following code

```
import pyscreeze

x, y = pyscreeze.locateOnScreen("Apple_Logo.png", confidence=0.5)
```

Comment: Kyles-MacBook-Pro-12:Python brogan$  cd /Users/brogan/Desktop/Python ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/brogan/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 57391 -- /Users/brogan/Desktop/Python/AutoGUI.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brogan/Desktop/Python/AutoGUI.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pyscreeze

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: ^ this is the terminal output after running your code. I had tried this before more or less and it was unsuccessful.

Comment: try reinstalling these libraries (pyscreeze, pillow, pyauogui)